# How to execute a function on setf place

Tags: common-lisp, setter, clos, setf

I have a list which contains some symbols and values. The goal is to setf the class slot with the accessor, whose symbol is provided by the list :

```
(defclass my-class ()
 ((attr :accessor attr)))

(let ((to-call '(attr "some-value"))
      (obj (make-instance 'my-class)))
 (setf `(,(car to-call) obj) (cadr to-call)))
```

I have tried via a macro :

```
(defmacro call-accessor (to-call)
 `(setf (,(car to-call) obj) "some-value"))

(let ((to-call '(attr "some-value"))
      (obj (make-instance 'my-class)))
 (call-accessor to-call))
```

Which fails too, since `to-call` is a symbol and not a list.

- `eval` does not work since `to-call` is a lexical variable;
- It is not possible to do a `let` over the macro to give it the list;
- I have tried with `with-slots` and `with-accessors` but the problem remains the same, because they are macros too.
- I have considered macros which declares other macro, and symbol-macrolet too.

How can I setf a slot via an accessor corresponding to a symbol in my list ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calling the accessor function**

> The goal is to setf the class slot with the accessor

An accessor is a pair of functions. You can get the part which sets the value via `FDEFINITION`. The name of the function is a list `(SETF accessor-name )`. This is unusual: Common Lisp has in this case function names which are not symbols, but lists.

```
CL-USER 14 > (let ((to-call '(attr "some-value"))
                   (obj (make-instance 'my-class)))
               (funcall (fdefinition `(setf ,(first to-call)))
                        (second to-call)
                        obj)
               (describe obj))

#<MY-CLASS 40200614FB> is a MY-CLASS
ATTR      "some-value"
```

Using a function `call-accessor`:

```
CL-USER 25 > (let ((to-call '(attr "some-value"))
                   (obj (make-instance 'my-class)))
               (flet ((call-accessor (obj to-call)
                        (funcall (fdefinition `(setf ,(first to-call)))
                                 (second to-call)
                                 obj)))
                 (call-accessor obj to-call)
                 (describe obj)))

#<MY-CLASS 402000220B> is a MY-CLASS
ATTR      "some-value"
```

**using SETF with APPLY to hide the FDEFINITION call**

To use `setf` with a computed accessor, one might need to use an `apply` form and a custom function.

Something like `call-accessor` would naturally be a function, because it does runtime lookup and takes values. Trying to use a macro would be more useful if the accessor would be known at *compile time*.

```
CL-USER 23 > (let ((to-call '(attr "some-value"))
                   (obj (make-instance 'my-class)))
               (flet (((setf my-setter) (new-value object accessor) 
                        (funcall (fdefinition `(setf ,accessor))
                                 new-value
                                 obj)))
                 (flet ((call-accessor (obj to-call)
                          (setf (apply #'my-setter obj (list (first to-call)))
                                (second to-call))))
                   (call-accessor obj to-call)
                   (describe obj))))

#<MY-CLASS 40200009AB> is a MY-CLASS
ATTR      "some-value"
```

**Choice of data structure**

I think it's okay to compute accessor functions and similar. There may be use cases for that. CLOS was designed to be dynamic and reflective to allow these things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setf` of [`slot-value`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_slt_va.htm#slot-value), using the slot name symbol in your data pair:

```
(let ((to-call '(attr "some-value")))
  (setf (slot-value obj (first to-call)) (second to-call)))
```

However, using `slot-value` directly is usually only sensible when you are wrangling at object internals (like initialize-instance methods/combinations; or maybe you are working on some serialization mechanism).

If that is not the case, you are using the object just as an associative data structure.  I'd suggest using an alist, plist, or hash-map instead.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have tried something like (setf `(slot-value ,obj ,(car to-call)... (which fails) but i do not understand how i can use setf of slot-value to sove the problem.

Comment: Note that this uses the slot name (not the accessor) and by accident/design the name of the slot and the accessor are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that an alternative structure like a `hash-table` should probably be used. But to extend [Svante's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583652) answer regarding `slot-value`, the working code is simply:

```
(setf (slot-value obj 'attr) "some-value")
```